# Z Axis homes, then bounces up 15 mm and stays there when printing

Tags: marlin, z-axis, reprap

Prusa, I3 Mk2.
Marlin 2.0.3

The test model printed fine prior to installing Marlin 2.0.3. It's not the slicer or GCode. I tried several models, and all of them worked perfectly prior to the update. The video below shows what's happening. The Z axis homes, then when the heating is over the head centers, and rises to 15 mm (as shown on the display). The print starts, the head doesn't move down but the display shows 0.1 mm. I know I missed something in the Configuration.h but I can't figure out what.

Comment: This sounds like the G-code contains a bad command. Might you share the first about 50-100 lines of G-code? We can cut it back then. If it is too long, pastebin is a good choice for the whole thing. Another possibility might be wrong Steps/mm on the Z-axis

Comment: So the code worked just fine previously. This only happened after the firmware update. The model was never re-sliced.


https://pastebin.com/V7QSS83M

The only thing different about the firmware config was the enabling of Mesh bed leveling. I assume that's the issue but I have no clue.

Comment: ok, I see no misplaced Z-movement commands, this must be in the firmware. Now, we would need that...

Comment: Could the firmware have a misconfigured Z axis offset (stale data in EEPROM?) or similar?

Comment: Welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Please post a link to your configuration.h, e.g. posted on PasteBin so we can help you. Also post the brand, this isn't an original Prusa, or is it?

Comment: I assume I have an offset that is  being manipulated by the mesh leveling but I truly don't know.

https://pastebin.com/sCmcCzJt - Configuration.h

The printer is a Reprap Guru, I3 Mk2, Ramps 1.4

Comment: In the video, you can see on the screen where it shows the Z distance to be 15mm during warm up, then once the extruder is up to temp and it moves to print, you can see it believes it is at a Z distance of "0". Somewhere between the warm up and print it is getting the idea it needs to reset its distance to zero. I'd be looking in the G-code as to where it's doing this, which might give you a clue as to *why it's doing it*.

Comment: The GCode is posted above, and again, it was not modified from a previously working version. This only started after the FIRMWARE update.   
Has anyone got any experience with the Mesh bed leveling, I'm thinking maybe that's part of the issue.